# Inserting the current year into a TextView

Tags: android, date

Just a small problem really, I want to place the current year into the footer of my apps. Each footer is a TextView, which is seen on menu screens etc. Is there a way to insert the year into this dynamically?

Cheers,
Laurence

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

TextView footer = findViewById(R.id.footer);
footer.setText("" + year);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Guys this is the code by what you can achieve the dropdown array of last 15 years (As the vehicle registration is valid for 15 years in India). So you can show this by the below code on Spinner dropdown in android.

    ArrayList<YearModel> arrayListYear=new ArrayList<>();
    int year,startYear,endYear;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            startYear=year-15;
            endYear=startYear+14;

            arrayListYear.clear();
            for(int i=startYear;i<=endYear;i++){
                arrayListYear.add(new YearModel(""+i));
            }

            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            for(YearModel model : arrayListYear) {
                names.add(model.getName());
                Log.e("Year","==>"+names);
            }

            spCarBuyYear.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MotorInsuranceActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, names));
```